# Design of listbox in silverlight windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have a code like that:

```
    <ListBox Height="522" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,162,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="448" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Height="48" Width="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Width="370">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="36" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,20,20,0" Width="380" Height="Auto"/>
                </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In Listbox i have 2 for-loop elements - image (icon) and text.
I need to fill the background of a particular image, but I do not know how to do it. In other words:
[image]

sorry for little stupid question and thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just need to add a background to the `StackPanel`. Change the color and opacity properties until you get the effect that you want.

```
<ListBox Height="522" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,162,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="448" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132" Padding>
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.4" />
                </StackPanel.Background>
                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Height="48" Width="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
                <StackPanel Width="370">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="36" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,20,20,0" Width="380" Height="Auto"/>
            </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: What if, instead of black I need to fill in the picture?
but anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: What do you mean by 'fill in the picture'? What picture? The `Image`? and what do you want to fill it in with?